# Run as Junit5 is missing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Below is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Below is my test case:

```
package com.myapp.backend;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class DistanceCalculatorTest {
@Test
public void smokeTest() {
    Location placeABC = new Location(41.3925603, 2.1418532);
    Location placaBCD = new Location(41.3870194,2.1678584);

    // More or less 2km 
    assertEquals(2.0, DistanceCalculator.calculateDistance(placeABC , placaBCD ), 0.5);
  }
}
```

I am not getting the option to run as JUnit 5 in Eclipse. I am using Eclipse Neon. When trying to use "Junit" from Run configuration, it is not able to find the test class.

[image]

When trying to select the test class, getting error, " Cannot find class 'junit.framework.TestCase' on project build path"

[image]

And the Maven dependencies are in build path:

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

JUnit 5 came out in late 2017. The last maintenance release for Neon was early 2017. Upgrade to Photon.